# Python - Error when updating value in dict using API

Tags: python, api

I am trying to update some data using API.

I am able to successfully update if is a simple field. However some of the fields that I am trying to update are dictionary, so I am having issues updating such fields.

Given below is how my data is:

```
emp_id, emp_name, pay_data
emp_101, Scott, {'annualSalary': 0.0, 'baseRate': 0.0}
```

If I were to update the prod_name I do the below

```
url = "https://api.paylocity.com/api/v2/companies/B123/employees/emp_101/?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=WebLinkAPI&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret"

payload = {'emp_name': 'Kevin'}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access} 
response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

The code works just well.

However if I need to update anything in the `pay_data` field as below I get `error code 400`

```
url = "https://api.paylocity.com/api/v2/companies/B123/employees/emp_101/?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=WebLinkAPI&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret"
payload = {'annualSalary': '100.0'}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access} 
response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: **Without knowing the website or specification for the API that is being used, it's difficult to answer your question.** Are you sure the field name is `basePrice` and not something else (you referred to it as `prod_price` in your description)? Also, what is the correct format for the actual value? Should there be some number of decimal places, for example `101.00`?

Comment: @Booboo I have updated my initial post with the details of the API I am using. Tool I am pulling data is `paylocity`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert from string to integer in `basePrice`
I mean like this `payload = {'basePrice': 101}` from '101'(string) to 101(integer)

Code:

```
  url = 'www.website.com'
  payload = {'basePrice': 101}
  headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access} 
  response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I have tried the suggested code as well still throwing the same error code 400

Comment: you're welcome , can you try to change http methods ? try [PATCH , PUT , POST ......]